# How to increase query performance in QuestDB? Will qdb index help or should I use something instead WITH keyword?

Tags: sql, performance, join, storage, questdb

I have a QuestDB database with 3 tables.

- Table Foo - 15 columns
- Table Bar - 30 columns
- Table Baz - 23 columns

Most columns are string or long data types. All tables are partitioned by DAY.

40 days of production collected data using about 120GB of disk space.

Server has 4 CPU cores and 4 GB of RAM

All the queries via pg protocol where I'm trying to JOIN two of my tables are taking too long to execute (Up to several minutes per query).

Sample query:

```
WITH joined_bar_and_foo AS
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM 'foo' 
    INNER JOIN 'bar' ON 'foo'.trigger_id = 'bar'.trigger_id 
    WHERE 'bar'.some_internal_id = 24 
      AND 'bar'.timestamp > '2023-08-01T00:00:00.000Z' 
      AND 'bar'.timestamp < '2023-08-01T23:59:59.999Z' 
      AND 'foo'.another_internal_id = 777666 
) 
SELECT count_distinct(trigger_id) 
FROM joined_bar_and_foo 
WHERE some_field = 1 
  AND (another_internal_id=100 or another_internal_id=150);
```

Initially my server had 2 CPU cores, I increased it to 4 CPU cores but it's not helping.

All the server.conf settings about shared workers and writer page sizes are set to default.

Writing performance is good with Influx-line-protocol.

How can I increase my reading performance and what it's wrong with my config?

Should I recreate new tables from scratch with some kind of index for [string - trigger_id] filed as it is present in every table and I'm using it to join?

Maybe changing "Writer page size" configuration will help?

Maybe I should use something instead of WITH keyword to compose my join queries?

Answer (score 0):

`WITH` clause does not usually speed up queries and on contrary may prevent optimiser to eliminate some overhead.

```
SELECT count_distinct(trigger_id)
FROM 'foo' 
INNER JOIN 'bar' ON 'foo'.trigger_id = 'bar'.trigger_id 
WHERE 'bar'.some_internal_id = 24 
      AND 'bar'.timestamp > '2023-08-01T00:00:00.000Z' 
      AND 'bar'.timestamp < '2023-08-01T23:59:59.999Z' 
      AND 'foo'.another_internal_id = 777666 
      AND some_field = 1 
      AND (another_internal_id=100 or another_internal_id=150)
```

If you can restrict `foo` by designated timestamp it can yield the best optimisation since it will reduce amount of data scanned.

Hardware wise, adding more RAM or faster disk will improve the queries speed.